# What's a good research topic in Computer Graphics?

Tags: raytracing, rendering, 3d, 2d, model

I am currently trying to find topics for my master's thesis. I would really like to do something in the field of computer graphics, but I've been having trouble finding what are some current problems people are trying to solve. I don't consider myself very good in this area, but I am willing to learn.

If you could provide some direction it would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you talked with your supervisor? He ought to have some ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question does not really fit here since there is no clear answer to it and the answers you might get would be mostly opinion-based. Please have a look into [this page](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [this page](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) too learn what you can ask here.

Comment: You may read recent SIGGRAPH papers (2010-present) for ideas.